# cakephp Saving one to many manually

Tags: cakephp

I have model A which has many model B scenario. I have defined the dependancies in following way:

```
class A extends AppModel {
    var $hasMany = array(
                        'B' => array(
                                    'className' => 'A',
                                    'foreignKey' => 'keyword_id',
                                    'dependent' => true
                                    )
                    );
```

Class A has following column:

```
keyword
created
```

Class B(table B) has following column:

```
keyword_id
category_id
```

My problem is when I execute the code below I expect table B to have keyword_id and category_id corresponding to keyword_id.

```
    $data = array(
                   'A' => array(
                    'keyword' ( => 'zzzzz'
                            ),
                        'B' => array(
                                 3,4,5
                                 )
                        );
        $this->A->saveAll($data);
```

When I execute the following the script Table B only has "NUll" for the corresponding keyword_id. Is there something else I need to do different.

Comment: Please supply proper model names rather than “A” and “B”. It will improve readability and help us diagnose your issue easier.

Comment: Hi Martin, the class A is the "Keyword". This contains "keyword", "created" column. Class B is the "KeywordCategory" which stores the keyword_id and category_id.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your data is formatted correctly.  I believe it should be formatted more like this:

```
$data = array(
     0  => array(
         'A' => array(
               'keyword' => 'zzzzzz',
               'created' => '',
          ),
         'B' => array(
              0 => array(
                  'category_id' => 3,
              ),
              1 => array(
                  'category_id' => 4,
              ),
              etc.,
          ),
     ),
     etc.,
);
```

Comment: This didnt work. It didnt event insert the rows in the table B(or KeywordCategory)

Answer (score 0):

you should have a data structure like user2076809 suggests (nice nickname by the way!) and if you're using Cake 2.X use the saveAssociated method, as in:

```
$this->A->saveAssociated($data);
```